# Не отображаются элементы после RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Как сделать чтобы после  RecyclerView отображался  LinearLayout

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_recountData_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView_Porods_id">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonId_addStepToWood"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="+" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonId_delStepToWood"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="-" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это весь код разметки? выглядит как два независимых элемента

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Максимально непонятно какой родительский элемент и у вас на скриншоте два списка а в вопросе упоминается только один. Если вы планируете использовать `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` то можно сделать так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_Porods_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_recountData_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView_Porods_id">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView_recountData_id"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonId_addStepToWood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="+" />
        
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonId_delStepToWood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="-" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я добавил цвета чтобы более понятно где какой список находится. Так же можно использовать и простой LinearLayout с вертикальной ориентацией. Тэг который вам вообще был нужен этот:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView_recountData_id"
```

если простыми словами то вы верх элемента с этим тэгом выравниваете по отношению к элементу с указанным id